# Seconds to hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: math

I am very bad at math, but what is the mathematical equation (in its simplest possible form) to convert 3605 seconds to hours, minutes and seconds?

`3605 / 60 / 60 = 1,0013888888 hours`

Am I on the right track?

```
time.hours = seconds / 3600;
time.minutes = (seconds - 3600 * time.hours) / 60;
time.seconds = seconds - 3600 * time.hours - 60 * time.minutes;
```

This doesn't work, but it should, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you mean days, not dates.

Comment: No, I must have mistyped. I want to convert it to hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Comment: what programming language are you using? do the types of the variables and the / operator support integer division?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track. Here's a breakdown.

3605 secs

60 sec in a minute 3605/60 = 60.083 minutes

60 minutes in an hour 60.083 = 1.001 hour

24 hours in a day 1.001/24 = .0417 of a day

Answer (score 0):

```
1 minute = 60 seconds
1 hour = 60 minutes = 60*60 seconds
```

So, 
if

```
x = 3605
a = number of hours
b = number of minutes
c = number of seconds
```

then

```
a = ⌊ x / (60*60) ⌋
b = ⌊ (x - (a*60*60)) / 60 ⌋
c = x - ((a*60*60) + (b*60))
```

⌊⌋ means [quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient)

Comment: c = x - ((a*60*60) + (b*60))
this should be minus not plus
c = x - ((a*60*60) - (b*60))

Comment: #Mohamed DZ Can you explain why? I don't think that is correct. Did you miss the outer most brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Let t be the total number of seconds

```
h = int(t / 3600)
m = int((t - 3600 * h) / 60)
s = t - 3600 * h - 60 * m
```

See code here: http://ideone.com/OzLF8g

Comment: This doesn't work. 3601 should be 1 h 0m 1s, but instead the result is like 1h 0,0000001m 0s

Answer (score -1):

```
hours = seconds // 3600
minutes = (seconds // 60) % 60
sec = seconds % 60
```

try it

Comment: answer to the question not just mention the transformation